# SignalR signs out ServiceStack session

Tags: javascript, asp.net, servicestack, signalr

I seem to have a strange problem between ServiceStack and SignalR. Both services work ok, no odd activity, SignarlR Hub loads successfully and works as expected. ServiceStack authenticates via Google ok, no issues there.

However, once I sign into the site with SS, all is fine, problem seems comes when I navigate to a page that is using SignalR. Once the javascript for SignalR has inititalised, it seems to clear all session info for ServiceStack on the server. Meaning if I refresh the page, I get redirected back to login. However, if I leave the page as is, the SignalR notifications arrive as expected.

Anyone got any ideas what could be going on?

My simple code is based off the StockTicker example. Here it is:

```
<HubName("salesTicker")> _
```

Public Class VerificationLogHub
    Inherits Hub
    Private ReadOnly _verificationTicker As VerificationLogTicker

```
Public Sub New()
    Me.New(VerificationLogTicker.Instance)

End Sub

Public Sub New(verTicker As VerificationLogTicker)
    _verificationTicker = verTicker
End Sub

Public Function GetAllLogs() As IEnumerable(Of UI_GuestBook)
    Return _verificationTicker.GetAllLogs()
End Function

Public Sub start()
    _verificationTicker.StartMonitoring()
End Sub

Public Sub [stop]()
    _verificationTicker.StopMonitoring()
End Sub
```

End Class

The Ticker class is virtually identical to the StockTicker example only difference being, I'm fetching my data from my database not obviously not generating randon stock prices.

And here's the page javascript that gets the ball rolling.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        var ticker = $.connection.salesTicker;
        $.connection.hub.start().pipe(init);


        function init() {
            return ticker.server.getAllLogs().done(function (guestBooksLog) {
                ticker.server.start();
                if(guestBooksLog.length>0)
                    updateStats(guestBooksLog[0]);
            });
        }

        $.extend(ticker.client, {
            updateStockPrice: function (GuestBook) {
                updateStats(GuestBook);
            }
        });
    });

    function updateStats(GuestBook) {
        $('#spanLsRate').html((GuestBook.Rate * 100).toFixed(1));
        $('#spanDcCount').html(GuestBook.TotalCount);

        console.log("Stats updated...");


    }
```

Comment: Seems I was mistaken, the issue has resurfaced. I thought a tweak to the application pool had fixed it, but it hadn't. And the issue is way larger than I thought. SignalR seems to be restarting the entire application, everyone is signed out.

Comment: can you please show us some code?

Comment: Added some of the code in use. The VerificationLogTicker class is virtually the same as the StockTicker example, but I can paste it if it'll help.